# Forcing a bat file out of an endless loop

Tags: batch-file

I have the following endless loop in at bat file that uses blat to send email.

```
:sendmail
sleep 5
blat my.log -subject "Test Mail" -server company.server.com -tf names.lst 
if errorlevel 1 goto sendmail
```

I have it loop because sometimes the mail server is busy and won't send my email the second the request is received, but it will send it a few seconds later. So this thing just keeps looping every 5 seconds if the server is busy. But if the server is down for the entire day, I would like to break out of the endless loop, say, after 30 minutes. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: 30 minutes or a successful send, whicever comes first?

Answer (score 2):

Create a variable to keep track of the number of seconds you've waited. Each time through the loop, check if you've waited 1,800 seconds (30 minutes) or more. If you have, break out of the loop.

The below code is untested.

```
SET SecondsWaited=0
:sendmail
IF %SecondsWaited% GEQ 1800 GOTO EMAILFAIL
SET /A SecondsWaited+=5
sleep 5
blat my.log -subject "Test Mail" -server company.server.com -tf names.lst 
if errorlevel 1 goto sendmail

:EMAILFAIL
```

Comment: You can also use `goto :EOF` to jump to the end of the batch file.

Comment: Thank you David! Will this code a whirl!
Much appreciated!
Bruce